# Is there a way to run unit test for a WebGL webapp in a headless browser

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, webgl, phantomjs, glge

Is there a way to run unit test for a WebGL (GLGE) webapp in a headless browser?

I'd like to run the tests on a jenkins server, so the tests must run on a headless (phantom.js) brower.

Anybody already tried that?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried *any* GL apps on this headless machine? Windows used to have software-driven OpenGL in it, but that was back in the days of XP.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2020 using [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) is probably the easiest way to use a headless browser that supports WebGL.

You can also [use Chromium in headless mode](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) directly

Comment: Broken link the first one

Comment: @DerekLawrence, updated the answer instead of just the link