# WebGL apps (Cesium) in headless browser with xvfb

Tags: firefox, headless, xvfb, cesiumjs, slimerjs

I am trying to run Cesium (http://cesiumjs.org/) with a headless firefox. I also tried slimerjs. In both cases, I am using xvfb, and get this:

```
[azureuser@myvm.net slimerjs-0.9.5]$ ./slimerjs test.js

Script Error: uncaught exception: RuntimeError: The browser supports WebGL, but initialization failed.
RuntimeError@http://myvm.net/Cesium/Cesium.js:11697:19
Context@http://myvm.net/Cesium/Cesium.js:97405:1
Scene@http://myvm.net/Cesium/Cesium.js:122319:23
CesiumWidget@http://myvm.net/Cesium/Cesium.js:132474:25
@http://myvm.net/:254:22
x.Callbacks/l@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js:4:24877
x.Callbacks/c.fireWith@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js:4:25702
.ready@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js:4:2898
S@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js:4:551

       Stack:
         -> undefined: 0
```

I did look around online, but did not find any satisfactory answer. There is this: [Is there a way to run unit test for a WebGL webapp in a headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763325/is-there-a-way-to-run-unit-test-for-a-webgl-webapp-in-a-headless-browser), but it did not generate many replies, and the only answer is not accepted.

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate why the suggested answer is unacceptable? I mean - what is your need? (this might lead me to a solution that best fits your need. The suggested answer seems to be related to Continous Integration process).

Comment: @HenryAloni What was the answer?